# Алгоритм рисования геометрических задач

Tags: алгоритм, php, геометрия, canvas, javascript

Есть ли какой-то алгоритм, который по данным рисует рисунок к задаче?

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду ? пример данных пожалуйста.

Comment: Исчо адын криптовопрос...

Comment: может быть ему блоксхему нужно?

Comment: Я прошу прощения за столь долгий ответ.
Пример: точка А, точка В, прямая а, треугольник А В С, отрезок М N, отрезок пересекается с прямой а

Comment: 2D или 3D ?

Answer (score 1):

[Геометрические алгоритмы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B) . Также изучайте графические библиотеки (к примеру на php это GD2, ImageMagick) и рисуйте что Вам потребуется.

Comment: Простите, но ссылка ведет на эту страницу

Comment: >Простите, но ссылка ведет на эту страницу

а это уже рекурсия

Comment: >а это уже рекурсия
может пошутили так?

Comment: @IVsevolod сомневаюсь . Я тоже несколько раз сталкивался с подобным - публикуешь нормальную ссылку на страницу, а она в итоге ведет на эту же самую страницу

Comment: Сейчас несколько раз пробовал исправить ссылку в ответе, но тоже ничего не вышло. Видимо, какой-то баг сайта. В общем, зайдите по этому адресу: ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Категория:Геометрические_алгоритмы

Comment: Подтверждаю, наблюдал данную проблему у себя в ответе, причем при редактирование сама ссылка видна в круглых скобках.

Comment: @DreamChild ясно, буду знать о такой проблеме )